# Add plus sign to batch file url

Tags: batch-file, url-parameters

I have a batch file which opens a pop-up within a website. The website opens fine, but when I want to add a parameter with a plus character, `+`, it doesn't work!

The code looks like this:

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --app=https://website.com?phone=%1
```

However the `%1` will be replaced with the incoming number but without the `+` before it.

I don't why that happens so I tried to add a plus manually.

```
@echo off
start "Chrome" chrome --app=https://website.com?phone=+%1
```

But that doesn't work either!

Does anyone have an idea how to add the `+` sign to the url?

The desired result should be:

```
https://website.com?phone=+3112345678
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `+` is the url encoding for `space`.

To encode a plus sign you have to use `%2b`.
But in batch-files the percent sign is also a special character, therefore it has to be escaped itself by another percent sign.

```
 https://website.com?phone=%%2B555-123
```

And the url should be quoted, because when more than one get parameter is present, then these parameters are separated by `&` signs, that collides again with the special meaning in batch files for command separation.

```
start "Chrome" chrome --app="https://website.com?phone=%%2B%1&name=John"
```